# Codebuild local build artifacts only readable by root user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I'm using AWS codebuild to build locally (see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/announcing-local-build-support-for-aws-codebuild/).

I run the build with the following command:

```
./codebuild_build.sh -i aws/codebuild/standard:4.0 -a artifacts -s .
```

When the build is done, here's the content of my "artifacts" repo:

```
total 114612
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 117360014 mai   18 15:51 artifacts.zip
```

Is there any way to make sure Codebuild applies different permissions to this artifacts file ?

Answer (score 0):

The script doesn't by default. As you have the script locally, why not add a 'chmod' line to change the permissions.